# Cannot redeclare a function error

Tags: php, function, php-5.3, magic-quotes-gpc

I am trying to remove the slashes from magic quotes from an array. So I have two functions, one is to remove the slashes, another is to set the variable.

```
// Strip slashes from an array.
function strip_magic_quotes($array)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        function stripslashes_array($array)
        {
            return is_array($array) ? array_map('stripslashes_array', $array) : stripslashes($array);
        }
        return stripslashes_array($array);
    }
    return $array;
}

function set_variable($array = array(),$key,$params = array())
{
    # If $params is not an array, let's make it array with one value of former $params.
    if(!is_array($params)) $params = array($params);
    if(!is_array($array)) parse_str($array, $array);

    # Strip slashes from the array if get_magic_quotes_gpc is on.
    $array = strip_magic_quotes($array);

    # This will return true or false.
    if(in_array('boolean', $params)) return isset($array[$key]) ? true : false;

    # This will regard '0' as a string.
    # Return value or 0 as a string.
    elseif(in_array('0', $params)) return isset($array[$key]) && ($array[$key] == '0') ? trim($array[$key]) : null;

    # Return null as string if 'null_to_string' is set.
    elseif(in_array('null_to_string', $params)) return isset($array[$key]) && !empty($array[$key]) ? trim($array[$key]) : 'null';

    # Check if the key is an array.
    elseif(isset($array[$key]) && !empty($array[$key]) && is_array($array[$key])) return isset($array[$key]) && !empty($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : null;

    # This will regard '0', empty space as falsey.
    # Return value or null.
    else return isset($array[$key]) && !empty($array[$key]) ? trim($array[$key]) : null;
}

$array = array(
    'name'=>'Hello',
    'type'=>'{"page":"page"}'
);


# set the required array.
$items_variable = array(
    'name',
    'type'
);

# loop the array.
foreach( $items_variable as $item_variable )
{
    # set the main variables.
    $$item_variable = set_variable($array,$item_variable);
}

print_r($type);
```

I get this error in my live server which I don't understand it,

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare stripslashes_array() (previously
>   declared in json.php:16) in
>   json.php on line 16

**line 16** refers to this line `function stripslashes_array($array)` which does not seem to have any mistake.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Disable magic quotes :( It's removed in the latest PHP version for a reason.

Comment: So does it mean that we don't have to worry about magic quotes in the latest PHP version?

Comment: @lauthiamkok, yes.  Our long international nightmare is over.

Comment: which version is this PHP? my live server is still having magic quotes!! :(

Comment: @lauthiamkok, [release 5.4](http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php).

Comment: my live server is 5.3.10... no luck!

Comment: You can disable magic quotes in the server configuration.

Comment: how? it is a live server not a localhost...

Comment: @lauthiamkok, you're close.  Maybe you can convince them to upgrade.  There aren't that many [backwards incompatible changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php).

Comment: Thanks. They told me to use .htaccess file and place:

`php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off`

and it is now off for good! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that everytime you call the function `strip_magic_quotes` PHP tries to declare the function `stripslashes_array`.

Why do you think you want to nest that function? If you really want to do it this way (which you shouldn't) you can change it to:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() && !function_exists('stripslashes_array')) {
```

Although this fixes the issue you simply shouldn't do it in the first place, because:

- it would be better to disable (if possible) magic* for the better of mankind.
- declaring functions in functions (although possible) should really be avoided in almost all cases.

Or you could simply just drop that inner function completely if you don't need it somewhere else and just let the code run in the outer function.

Comment: can't remove it from ini php in my server... unless there are tricks to do so :-(

Comment: Perhaps get other hosting? :P

Comment: barely to get a hosting company does php 5.4 here in the UK unless you know any?

Comment: @lauthiamkok you don't need PHP 5.4. You just need to be able to disable magic_quotes in the configuration. Are let the hosting company do it for you. There should be NO reason at all to have magic* enabled. Now that I think of it it wouldn't sirprise me if `Register globals` is also enabled in the config.

Comment: Also besides the fact that you should disable it I have also provided two work-arounds for your problem (whether it is disabled or not).

Comment: I will talk to them to turn it off! :-)

Comment: @lauthiamkok just be cautions when doing it on a running website. E.g. are you DAMN sure all your queries are safe against attacks. e.g. SQL injection or you will make your website vulnerable everywhere you query the db.

Comment: Thanks. I use PDO for all database injections, shouldn't it be safe?

Comment: PDO alone doesn't make you SQL statements safer, but [prepared statements do](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Yes, I prepare statements before injecting :-) Thank you very much for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Nested named functions are almost useless for exactly this reason.

You have to either move the nested function out or do an explicit `function_exists` check.

You can consider using an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in PHP 5.3 or above.

Comment: thanks. I haven't done any code with an anonymous function... not sure how to do it practically (not really understand the examples in php.net doc either...).

Comment: Try the [second example](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-161).